# How can I implement JPA Auditing like functionality in Quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm using Quarkus framework, and I want to implement functionality similar to JPA auditing like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class EntityAuditInfo {

    @CreatedBy
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    private Integer createdBy;
    @CreatedDate
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    private Integer modifiedBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_on")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedOn;
....
```

I have tried searching it in Quarkus documention but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported (although not really documented as it's a standard Hibernate/JPA feature).

You can see some example usages in the Quarkus integration tests [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/2.16.1.Final/integration-tests/jpa/src/main/java/io/quarkus/it/jpa/entitylistener).